# NodeJS: Are callback functions or synchronous functions better to use in async/await?

Tags: node.js, performance, promise, async-await, bcrypt

Im currently in the process of converting some of my project's dependencies' to their own async / await functions for better development flow. Many of these dependencies such as bcrypt have options to use synchronous ( no callback ) functions or asynchronous ( callback ) functions. I have made a super small function that would convert the output of a bcrypt compare to my framework-friendly version that always returns a {success: true/false, result} object. Heres an example of what I have.

```
      async hashStringCompare (hashed, string) {
        try {
          const success = bcrypt.compareSync(string, hashed)
          if (!success) return {msg: 'The string does not match', success}
          return {msg: 'The string does match', success}
        } catch (err) {
          return {err, msg: 'Something bad happened', success: false}
        }
      },
```

The problem is, bcrypt offers two functions for comparing strings and hashed strings; compareSync and compare. If i formatted the code to use the compare function that uses callbacks, it would look like this:

```
       async hashStringCompare (hashed, string) {
         return new Promise((resolve) => {
           bcrypt.compare(string, hashed, (err, success) => {
             if (err) resolve({ err, msg: 'An error has occured.', success })
             resolve({success, msg: 'The string does match' })
           })
         })
        }
```

Really my goal is to get every function with a callback converted to a promise-based format, but my question is this; Which one of the above do you think would be overall more performance friendly? Technically. both functions are asynchronous, but which one do you believe is faster?

If the way i'm structuring this code seems illogical, please tell me. I'm not sure if this is the best way to format non-breaking code, so I would love any feedback regarding this.

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I would really appreciate any advice you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are callback functions or synchronous functions better to use in async/await?

You want to use the async version of the functions, because the sync versions block and can't be used asynchronously. (By "block" I mean they cause the thread of execution to be suspended until their result is read, so they are not asynchronous at all.)

I believe the bcrypt library async functions—like many libraries these days—let you omit the callback argument. If you omit the callback, the functions return a Promise, which you can then use with `await`. So, for example:

```
const result = await bcrypt.compare(string, hashed)
```

Here the function executes asynchronously, but it looks like a synchronous call because you used `await`. If you hadn't used `await`, then you could have used the Promise directly, like:

```
bcrypt.compare(string, hashed).then(result => console.log(result))
```

but `await` hides the Promise from you and makes the code look synchronous.

> Technically. both functions are asynchronous

No, the first function is not asynchronous. Putting `async` in front of the function just enables you to use the `await` syntax inside of it, but that first variant is actually synchronous. The second variant is asynchronous, but you don't take advantage of `async` in that variant either, because you're not using `await` like in my example above. You can remove the `async` from both of those variants and nothing will change.

> but which one do you believe is faster?

They're probably both the same speed, but if you need concurrency, meaning if you have many requests that need to happen at the same time, you need to use the async version of the call because Javascript only has one thread that it makes available to your code. So if you use the sync version, that thread will block execution for all other requests. The async version calls out to other threads not available to Javascript, and enable many bcrypt computations to happen concurrently.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. thought that adding async would cause the function to run on a seperate thread, but apparently I was wrong. So if I understand you correctly, using 'await' before a promise in asynchronous functions causes the process to leap to another thread, then come back to the main thread with the result? Thanks again for the fast response.

Comment: Yep, `await` in front of a promise-returning call lets you avoid using `.then()`, and instead allows you to get the result of the call as though it was a synchronous call. You can also then use `try/catch` instead of `.catch()`. The `await` doesnt cause it to leap to another thread. It would leap to another thread anyway. It just lets you get the result without passing a callback, either to `.then()` or directly to the call itself.

Comment: What "causes" the leap to another thread is using an API with a callback. Somewhere in the internals of that API it will perform that "leap", and then call your callback with the result. `async` just lets you use `await` inside the body of a function: that is all it does.

Comment: Ok, that seems to make sense. I am however, still struggling with understanding promises now. My previous understanding was that when you called a promise, it started that process on a seperate thread, so you could run other code while it was processing the promise. If that's not how it works, how do both sets of code run at the same time on the main thread? If that is how it works, since async functions always return promises, why wouldn't they always run on different threads?

Comment: Your understanding of promises is correct per your description above. `async` functions don’t always returns promises. They only return a promise if you return one from them.

Comment: An “asynchronous” function is a non-language thing that just means “this function takes a callback and doesn’t block”. An `async` function is a syntax feature that lets you mark a function as allowing `await` inside its body. there’s no reason to mark a function `async` unless you intend to use `await` inside of it, but JS won’t stop you from doing so

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it. I guess I still have some learning to do in order to understand the whole concept of how javascript handles separate threads. Your responses helped a lot!

Comment: That is great to hear. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Should point out that marking a function `async` does do one thing, besides allowing `await` inside its body: If a function is marked `async`, it automatically wraps any returned values in a Promise.